# "how soon I get" vs. "how soon I will get"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, future

What is the difference between the following:

> It depends on how soon I get my visa.
>
> It depends on how soon I will get my visa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Will" implies something is going to happen in the future (in this case, getting your visa). But it's unnecessary in the first sentence: "*how soon*" provides enough context that you don't need the word "*will*." Like rudra, I'd interpret both sentences as conveying the same meaning.  In fact, I might also suggest:

> It depends on when I get my visa.

as that would essentially mean the same thing, too.

However, if you were asking the question:

> "How soon will I get my visa?"

then the "will" *is* necessary. (You wouldn't say, "How soon I get my visa?")

Comment: How come a simple present structure be used in this context? If you could elaborate on it as the event is something that doesn't seem to fit in a *simple present* context.

Comment: It's all in the use of "how soon" (or "when"), and the pronoun "it." What if I asked you to replace "it" with what the "it" stands for? In that case, you might say something like, "When I will buy my ticket depends on how soon I get my visa" or "I will buy my ticket sometime after I get my visa." (Aha! That's where the future tense is buried in this sentence).

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Leach said in a comment, it is not usual in English to use "will" as an auxiliary in an embedded temporal or concessive clause. You usually see this with "when" and "if", but this is also a kind of temporal clause.

Comment: +1. For mentioning temporal or concessive clauses.